# Why are both these scala pattern matching extractor calls valid syntax?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

tl;dr; It's because of infix operators, nothing to do with extractors

I've been playing around with extractors in scala and found the fact that both the cases below are valid syntax a bit puzzling?!  What's the story?

```
class Foo(val items:List[String], val number:Int)

object FooEnough {
  def unapply(f:Foo):Option[(List[String], Int)] = if(f.number > 2) Some(f.items, f.number) else None
}

val foo = new Foo("a" :: "b" :: "c" :: Nil, 3)
val matches:String = foo match {
  case FooEnough("a" :: "b" :: "c" :: Nil, 3) => "first case"
  case "a" :: "b" :: "c" :: Nil FooEnough 4 => "second case"
}
//matches == "first case"
```

If I create another extractor, which extracts 3 parameters, how am I meant to call this using the syntax as in the 2nd case above?

```
object FooSpectrum {
  def unapply(f:Foo):Option[(String, List[String], Int)] =
    if(f.number > 2) Some("zx", f.items, f.number) else None
}

foo match {
  case FooSpectrum("zx", "a" :: "b" :: "c" :: Nil, 3) => "first case" //compiles
  case "zx" FooSpectrum "a" :: "b" :: "c" :: Nil 4 => "second case" //doesn't compile
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the infix operator magic scala provides. You can also write `String Map Int` instead of `Map[String,Int]`. This only works for binary types/functions, because it would make no sense for more than 2 args and would also be hard to parse.

Comment: ah ok, it's nothing to do with extractors then.  Thanks!